# Can you track subcontractor costs in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I am looking into MS Project and before I purchase, I need to make sure it can do what I need it to do.

Lets say I have 2 roofing subcontractors that I would use for a project.  Each contractor would perform 1 of a list of tasks I have established and I have a list of all prices for these tasks.

Can I store all of the following information for each vendor in MS Project?
Contractor, Tasks they would perform, price for each task.

Roof Contractor 1:

- Roof Maintenance (per house)  $150.00
- Replace Sheathing (per sheet) $40.00
- Replace Roof (per square)     $180.00

Roof Contractor 2:

- Roof Maintenance (per house)  $160.00
- Replace Sheathing (per sheet) $45.00
- Replace Roof (per square)     $190.00

For example: Project 1
Tasks:

- Roof Replacement (20 squares): $160.00
- Replace Sheathing (2 sheets):  $45.00

I would pick the roofer based on best price and availability at the time, but I would like to keep a list of all roofers, their tasks, and their prices in my project template.

Is this possible in MS Project?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is not directly, but you can make it work.

MS Project does not support fixed costs based on resource. You can have fixed costs on tasks, but they won't be dependent on which resource is assigned (aka which contractor). That said, you can work around this limitation as follows:

**For labor-driven tasks**, create a resource called "Contractor 1 maintenance" with a rate of $150/hour and assign this to your task with ***one hour of work***. The key is to always make sure the work on the task is just one hour (1h). Likewise, create another resource called "Contractor 2 maintenance" with a rate of $160/hour.

**For material-driven tasks**, create a resource called "Contractor 1 sheathing" with a rate equal to the sheet/sqft cost and assign this to your task with the work (e.g. hours) as the number of sheets required.

For both of these scenarios, make sure the task is set to "Fixed Duration" so that adding resource work does not affect the duration of the task.

Comment: Thank you @Rachel Hettinger.  I have a question about the materials example.  It seems I would be using the hours as the quantity of materials.  Is that correct?  If so I'm guessing setting it to fixed duration won't affect number of hours I can select?  Is that correct? (I'm not familiar with what fixed duration will do if I can still change the hours.)  Thank you for your reply!